# Device Orientation in IOS 6 portrait to landscape

Tags: ipad, ios6, uiinterfaceorientation

I want to rotate application in landscape and Portrait mode. I have one view controller. Once i rotate my device to landscape mode. portrait image and overlap landscape image.How can i achieve this please help me out with example. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is because of the **autoResizingMask**.

Give your UIImageView autoResizingMask as

```
myImage.autoresizingMask =  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
```